# ServletRegistrationBean in Spring cloud

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have recently migrated the application to Spring Cloud Gateway from zuul filter for routing to multiple microservices. I have a filter which is written in
native code (HTTPServlet). In Spring application initialization, I am registering that Servlet as below

```
@Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean oAuthCodeReceiverServletBean() {
        ServletRegistrationBean oauthCodeReceiverServletBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(
                new OAuthCodeRecieverServlet(), "/login/oauth/codereceiver");
        return oauthCodeReceiverServletBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<OAuthFilter> securityRegistrationBean() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<OAuthFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(oAuthFilter);
        registrationBean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        return registrationBean;
    }
```

But the Filter is not at all called. The filters that implements GlobalFilter are called. Is there a solution handle ?
Please note I dont have option to update the native code OauthFilter.

Comment: Spring Cloud Gateway is built on webflux and does not currently support servlets

Comment: So the only option is zuul gateway ?

Comment: Yes, but support for zuul in spring cloud ends this year.